# How to add prefix to MQ RFH2 Property Name using MQSETMP API form RPGLE?

Tags: ibm-mq, rpgle, rfh2

Faced a problem. I need to place an RFH2 message into MQ with Properties in the header.
If using the MQ API:

MQCRTMH
MQSETMP
MQPUT

then everything works as long as the name Property does not contain a prefix (for example, 'Property1') - WRKMQMQ shows that the message is in RFH2 format, shows that it contains Properties, shows the correct list of properties...

But as soon as I try add a prefix like 'ctx.Property1', everything stops working...
However, none of the above functions return an error. The message will be placed in MQ, but without RFH2 header and without properties.

The question is, how do I correctly prefix the property name?

Comment: OK I have seen the same behaviour when testing using the IBM supplied sample amqsstm.exe - I have also seen that if I put two properties into the message Handle and the second one has no dot in the name, then BOTH properties are added to the message. This sounds very much like a defect. Suggest you contact IBM and open a case.

Comment: Morag, thank you so much for paying attention to my question (I really hoped for it - last time you helped a lot) It will be difficult to bring all the code here. Here are the key points:

Comment: `dsPropName.VCHRP = %addr(PropName);`

`dsPropName.VCHRL = PropNameLen;`

`MQSETMP(hConn : hMsg : dsMQSMPO : dsPropName : dsMQPD : PropType :  PropValLen : %addr(PropVal) : OC : RC);`

Comment: ` dsMQPMO.PMOPT = %bitor(PMFIQ : PMNSYP : PMNCID);`

`dsMQPMO.PMVER = PMVERC;`

` dsMQPMO.PMOMH = hMsg;`

` dsMQMD.MDFMT = FMNONE;`

` MQPUT(hConn : hObj : dsMQMD : dsMQPMO : BuffLen : %addr(Buffer) : OC : RC);`

Comment: if PropName = 'Property001' I see in WRKMQMQ:

      GMT       GMT                                                     
 Opt  Date      Time      Type      UserId        Format            Size
      20210921  10050820  DATAGRAM  Y2KU          MQHRF2             123

Comment: But if PropName = 'ctx.Property001' I see this:

     GMT       GMT                                                     
Opt  Date      Time      Type      UserId        Format            Size
     20210921  10023188  DATAGRAM  Y2KU                              27

Comment: Morag, You are right! I tried add two properties with names:
'ctx.Property001' and 'Property002'. The both of them was added to message and it put to MQ in RFH2 format.
It's really looks like defect - 'ctx.Property001' and 'Property002' - success, only 'Property002' - success but only 'ctx.Property001' - fail...

Comment: @MoragHughson, I found a solution. The fact is that by default, unless otherwise specified, the namespace 'usr' is used.
Those. 'PropertyName' will [laced into namespace 'usr'
But 'ctx.PropertyName' - into namspace 'ctx'
Apparently, RFH2 header is not generated when namespace 'usr' is empty.
And if you specify 'usr.ctx.PropertyName', everything works correctly

Comment: @VictorPomortseff in the future, update your question with the code rather than putting it in the comments - too hard to read code in comments.  Also, MQRFH2 messages have folders.  The default folders are: mcd & jms.  The first qualifier of your property will indicate which folder the property should be put into .   All user properties should be put into the usr folder as you have discovered.  In MQ/Java, if you use the set***Property methods with just the single property name (no qualifiers) i.e. XYZ then MQ will place the property in the usr folder by default.

Comment: @Roger, there are a couple of important points missing from the IBM documentation.

Comment: First, if the folder is not explicitly specified, MQSETMP places the property in the usr folder (i.e. PropertyName is completely identical to usr.PropertyName). But if the folder is explicitly specified, then the property is placed in it and ctx.PropertyName is not equal to usr.ctx.PropertyName (in the first case, the property is placed in the ctx folder outside of usr, in the second - in ctx inside usr) - so that the property is placed in the folder ctx inside the usr folder, you must explicitly specify usr.ctx. This undescribed, ambivalent behavior can be confusing.

Comment: Secondly (and this is the main thing) - nowhere is it described that MQPUT does not create an RFH2 message header if the usr folder is empty, even if there is another, not empty, folder outside usr. But at the same time, if there are other properties in the usr folder, the header will be created and it will contain both the usr folder and other forlders outside of it. It was this fact that turned out to be a stumbling block for me yesterday.

Comment: I suspect the "described, ambivalent behaviour" is defective. Rather than asking IBM to describe it, I suggest you ask them to fix it! :-) As noted in my earlier response, I believe your next step should be to raise a case with IBM. Glad to see you have lots of data to give them though. You could write a answer for others, and then update it with anything you get back from IBM in way of an APAR later

Comment: @MoragHughson, unfortunately, I work for a company that is a "premium client" of IBM and cannot directly contact IBM over the head of the technical management.
I described the situation to the chief architect of the company, I hope that the decision will be made at his level.
The main problem, in my opinion, is the insufficient quality of the documentation. I have not found anywhere a mention of the fact that MQPUT does not form the RFH2 message header in the case when the usr folder does not contain any property, even if there is another, not empty, folder.

Comment: I suspect that is not documented because it is not meant to be that way. And frankly, you wouldn't want it to be that way either. To get code or doc updated you still need to open a case with IBM.

Comment: @MoragHughson, I agree that this behavior - when a property in a folder other than usr is placed in the header only when there are other properties in the usr folder - is rather strange. And I will try to convince our technical management to create a case on behalf of the company.

Comment: I am happy to hear you hope to raise a case with IBM. It would be a shame if a premium client was unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of important points missing from the IBM documentation:

1. If the folder is not explicitly specified, *MQSETMP* places the property in the *usr* folder (i.e. *PropertyName* is completely identical to *usr.PropertyName*). But if the folder is explicitly specified, then the property is placed in it and *ctx.PropertyName* is not equal to *usr.ctx.PropertyName* (in the first case, the property is placed in the *ctx* folder **outside** of *usr*, in the second - in *ctx* **inside** *usr*) - so that the property is placed in the folder *ctx* inside the *usr* folder, you must explicitly specify *usr.ctx*. This undescribed behavior can be confusing.
2. (and this is the main thing) - nowhere is it described that *MQPUT* does not create an *RFH2* message header if the *usr* folder is empty, even if there is another, not empty, folder outside *usr*. But at the same time, if there are other properties in the usr folder, the header will be created and it will contain both the *usr* folder and other forlders outside of it.

Thus, in my case, it is correct to name the property not *ctx.PropertyName*, but *usr.ctx.PropertyName*.

It should be borne in mind (which is also not reflected in the documentation) that if *PropertyName* or *usr.PropertyName* is passed to *MQSETMP*, the *MQINQMP* call after receiving the message will return the property name in the form *PropertyName* without *usr*.
But if *usr.ctx.PropertyName* is passed to *MQSETMP*, then *MQINQMP* will return the full name *usr.ctx.PropertyName*.